# sum of $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\big(\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{3n-2}+\frac{1}{3n-1}\big)$

Tags: limits, summation

My own idea is to use Squeeze Rule and use the inequality below to scale
$$\ln(n+1)<\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}<\ln(n)+1$$
But with this method I can't get the same value on both sides.
So what should be the right approach?
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I mean, $H_n$ is asymptotic with $\ln(n)+\gamma$, so then $H_{3n}-H_{2n}$ (which is your sum, more or less) is asymptotic with $\ln(3n)-\ln(2n)=\ln(3)-\ln(2)$. That's just intuition though, not a proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the same as the [left Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Left_Riemann_sum) for the integral of $1/x$ over the interval $[2,3]$ hence we have
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1{2n}+\frac1{2n+1}+\cdots+\frac1{3n-1}\right)
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{2+\frac{k}n}\\
&=\int_2^3\frac{1}{x}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\ln{(3)}-\ln{(2)}\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: I see ,using the definition of integral. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "atomic" relation that leads to the bounds you cited,
$$
\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)\le\frac1n\le\ln(n)-\ln(n-1).
$$
Then your sequence has the bounds, telescoping in the upper and lower sums,
$$
\ln(3n)-\ln(2n)\le\frac1{2n}+\frac1{2n+1}+\dots+\frac1{3n-1}\le \ln(3n-1)-\ln(2n-1),
$$
which then can be used with the "squeeze rule" (or "sandwich lemma").